# Express not recognizing request body

Tags: node.js, express, request

I can't get Express to recognize the body of my post requests. The following just sends back an empty object:

```
const express = require(`express`);
const router = express.Router();

router.post(`/`, async (req, res) => {
    res.send(req.body);
});
```

In another file, I also have:

```
const express = require(`express`);

const app = express();

app.use(express.json());
```

Here's the crazy part. This was working before. I already made a bunch of routes and everything worked fine, but I did something and now it doesn't. I'm even making the repo public if that helps: https://github.com/Wi-ll-iam/nodeSandbox

This is the body of the request I'm sending:

```
{
"name": "fakename"
"genre": "agrenera"
"director": "afknkeda"
"tags": ["adwadw", "wadadwa"]
}
```

I've tried using postman in chrome using a 'raw' body and also RESTClient in firefox, which is what I normally use. I've spent literally 4 hours on this and I'm about to rip my hair out.
[image: RESTCLient]

Comment: What bodyparser are you using? I don't see any bodyparser in your posted code

Comment: I didn't. That tag was included by mistake, sorry.

Comment: Then that's your answer. Express.js does not handle POST bodies. You need a body parser to get post bodies. The express project (not express module) has an official body parser middleware but you need to install and require it manually: https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser. I personally use formidable. This is simply not handled in Express

Comment: @slebetman you no longer need the `body-parser` package, just use `express.json()` and / or `express.urlencoded()` like OP _is_ already doing

Comment: I personally use formaidable instead of body-parser because body-parser does not handle multipart bodies (needed for file uploads). Note that since bodyparsers are 3rd party middleware it is up to the middleware how it wants to send the body to you. For example body-parser sets `req.body` but the one I use, formidable, sets `req.fields`. So read the documentation of your bodyparser

Comment: @William can you please show how you're making the request from the client-side? Also, you may want to use `res.json(req.body)` so it sets appropriate content-type headers

Comment: I added an image of the request I'm sending using RESTClient. That's all I'm using rn. There's a client folder in the repo but none of that stuff actually does anything.

Comment: Where / how do you set request headers in that client software? Express won't recognise your payload as JSON unless you set the appropriate content-type header

Comment: Oh, just noticed your payload isn't valid JSON; you're missing commas. Rule #1 when working with JSON: **never** roll your own

Comment: I corrected the payload syntax and still the same issue. I think it's somewhere in my JS code b/c I don't think I've changed anything about how I send the requests and they were working before. `content-type` header is `application/json; charset=utf-8`